# Failed to build capnproto on ARM, test failed

Tags: c++, embedded-linux, capnproto

I am trying to build `capnproto` library for linux arm machine using `arm-linux-gnueabihf-clang++` and it builds correctly but because tests is a part of a build it fails to finish build because i am building it on `x64` machine for arm platform and `capn` binary cannot be started on `x64` machine because it is compiled for `arm`. I was searching for similar problem and found that when you use make command you should not write `make -j6 check` but simply `make` , but this didn't help and using `--with-external-capnp` flag also didn't help. So the question is how to prevent running tests during the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When cross-compiling, you need to first build and install Cap'n Proto on the host machine, so that the commands `capnp` and `capnpc-c++` are available on the command line.

Once you've done that, you can cross-compile. Pass `--with-external-capnp` to `./configure` when configuring cross-compiling, to tell it to use the installed copy of the tools rather than the self-built copy. Also make sure you `make clean` or build in a different directory so that the build doesn't accidentally try to use the host-built objects.

If this "doesn't help", you'll need to provide more detail on what you're doing and what went wrong.